# Login token with sha256

Tags: security, authentication, token, sha256

I need to create a login token that I can pass from site 1 to site 2 in a querystring. I don't need to transfer a username or id, I just need to know on site 2 that the user has a valid login on site 1.

I currently create the token like this

```
timestamp|sha256(timestamp+secret)
```

On site 2 i create a sha256 of the given timestamp+secret, and match it with the given hash. I also check the timestamp, and doesn't validate if it's older than 5 min.

Is this a reasonably safe way of doing it?

Would it be easy to crack open the sha256 and get the secret?

Comment: I would like to point out the availability of [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/). You'll find experts there who can answer questions about the cryptography aspects of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) to provide an authenticated message between two parties that already have a shared secret key.  What you have described is very similar to an HMAC, because its a type of Message Authentication Code.  Although I would actually use an HMAC function to do this.

To crack an hmac you have to brute force secret using the the Authentication Code (the hashed part of the message).  The attacker knows the timestamp,  so they can keep guessing the secret.  Just make the secret really large and very random, like some output from /dev/random is a good choice.

Comment: It's not the same; HMAC protects from hash-extension attacks, simple concatenation does not.

Comment: That wasn't intended as a put-down, I'm sorry it came off that way. I want to make sure that while it appears very similar to HMAC, security-wise its very different. Crypto is—unfortunately—like that. The OP should follow your advice to use HMAC instead. (And SHA256 is vulnerable to length-extension attacks, almost all common hashes are, its simply not part of their design criteria to be resistant). See also http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/is-hklengthx-a-secure-mac-construction

Comment: @derobert let me ask you this,  is a length extension attack on sha256 a shortcut vs brute forcing the secret?  I would say probably not.  If he was using md5 or even worse md4 then i would be more concerned.  Regardless we agree that he should be using an hmac.

Comment: An "attack" on an algorithm is a shortcut vs. brute force—that's how cryptographers use the word. Basically, length-extension is that given HASH(x) and LENGTH(x) its fairly quick to compute HASH(x||y) where || is concatenation. There are variations of the attack that allow computing other extensions of the hash. These are real-world attacks; for example, Flickr had a vulnerability back in Sep. '09.

Comment: I should not also that I'm not a cryptographer, and I'm not sure that secret suffix (the "proper" name for the OP's algorithm, I believe) with SHA-256 is actually practically attackable. But the actual cryptographers seem to say "don't do that—use HMAC-SHA256", so I'm inclined to follow their advice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. HMAC it is.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rook says, you should use HMAC to authenticate your tokens.

Additionally, You need to ensure that your tokens can't be stolen. E.g., if you send that token in cleartext—either from site 1 to the user, or from the user to site 2, anyone listening in (think Firesheep) could also "prove" they have an account. The best you can do to prevent that is to use SSL/TLS.